# How can I check for 2 characters with a regular expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I used the following to check for two digits.

```
"^\d{2}$"
```

But how can I change this so I check for two digits or uppercase A-Z?

Comment: Are you looking for "Two digits or 1 uppercase character" or  "Two digits or 2 uppercase characters"?

Comment: Must be 2 characters and 0-9 or A-Z

Comment: A useful tool for authoring and/or testing regular expressions is http://www.regexpal.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 consecutive digits or 1 uppercase character:

```
\d{2}|[A-Z]
```

2 consecutive digits or 2 consecutive uppercase characters:

```
\d{2}|[A-Z]{2}
```

2 consecutive digit / uppercase characters:

```
[\dA-Z]{2}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^[A-Z|\d]{2}$
```

matches AA and 11 but not A, 1, AAA, or 111 (the A-Z specifies uppercase only)

Edit: This will also match 1A and C3 (see comment by Jason), if this is not what you want do not use this answer.

Comment: this will also match **1A** and **C3**, not exactly what she wants

Answer (score 1):

Use this, will match the items in bold only:

```
^\d{2}|[A-Z]{2}$
```

- **25**
- ab
- **AB**
- 2A
- A3
- -23
- -AB

If you also want to match against negatives, you can try this one:

```
^-?\d{2}|[^-][A-Z]{2}$
```

And will match these

- **25**
- ab
- **AB**
- 2A
- A3
- **-23**
- -AB